# CSS alignment of spans, inputs, and buttons

Tags: css, alignment

I'm looking for a way to align a number of elements (spans, inputs, and buttons) such that despite their differing sizes, their vertical mid point is on the same horizontal line:
[image: Alignment]

How do I achieve this in CSS? Here's the HTML file to play with:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css">
    <style>
.content { font-size: 18px; border: 1px dotted blue;  }
.content input, .content button { font-size: 40px; float: left; }
.label { border: 1px dotted red; float: left; }
.clear { clear: both; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="content">
    <span class="label">Label: </span><input type="text">
    <span class="label">More text: </span><input type="text">
    <button type="submit">Submit Me</button>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tada! http://www.brunildo.org/test/inline-block.html - check out the `vertical-align: middle` tests.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As others (David Nguyen and thirtydot) have said, adding `vertical-align:middle;` will accomplish the effect you're after *so long as* you get rid of the floats that are currently in your code. Adding `display:inline-block;` will let you have better control over the dimensions, and I don't know if you were planning on it, but I'd definitely swap out your `<span class="label">` for actual `<label>` tags.

Comment: Regarding `label` vs `span`, not sure it is a good idea to change all `span` for `label`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059861/whats-the-rendering-difference-between-a-span-and-label-tag

Answer (score 14):

Set the main `div`'s `line-height:` height of tallest element in px, then set `vertical-align: middle`.  You may have to set `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` on the subelements as well.

That should work.

Comment: Thanks Brian, that seems to work (at least in Chrome). Will leave the question open a bit longer to see if there are other interesting methods.

Comment: I noticed the input elements don't get aligned - they're left at the top. I can set their height and they'll look right, but is there a way to center them without setting them to full height?

Comment: You might have to add some margin or padding.

Answer (score 1):

Your span, input and button need the property:
`vertical-align:middle;display:inline`

Comment: Thanks David, but that doesn't seem to work. Give it a try with the html included in the question - it doesn't seem to do anything.